# Why does my second iMac keeps trying to pair with my other iMac via Bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth

I'm getting constant Bluetooth request on one iMac I own from a second iMac for no clear reason. Both are running the latest version of macOS Catalina.

It's not a keyboard or mouse this is definitely the iMac itself. If you press ignore device and cancel it just keeps coming back. Driving me nuts.